On Linear Relaxation of Convex Quadratic Maximization over Linear Constraints
Consider the following QP problem, where the matrix $Q$ is positive definite:
\begin{align*}
\max_{x} \quad & x^\top Qx + c^\top x \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & Ax \geq b, \\
                  & x \geq 0.
\end{align*}
Here, $x$ is a decision vector.
Linear Relaxation of QP Problem:
The linear relaxation is defined as
\begin{align*}
\max_{x,X} \quad & \text{tr}(QX) + c^\top x \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & Ax \geq b, \\
                  & AX \geq b x^\top, \\
                  & x, X \geq 0,
\end{align*}
where $\text{tr}(QX) := \sum_{i,j} Q_{ij} X_{ij}$. We know that the optimal value of the last problem provides an upper bound to the QP.
Question: Is this upper bound the optimal value? If not, could you provide an example demonstrating why this is not the case?

Was your previous question adequately addressed https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/on-linear-relaxation-of-standard-quadratic-programming ?

@MarkL.Stone Yes.
